# My If let statement is failing and I'm not sure why

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement, mapkit

Here is my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    // Make sure we are acting on the correct segue
    if segue.identifier == "CreateJumpSpot", let jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC = segue.destination as? JumpSpotCreatorController {
        // Set the delegate in the JumpSpotCreatorController we're navigating to
        jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC.delegate = self
        
    } else if segue.identifier == "JumpSpotInfo", let jumpSpotInfoVC = segue.destination as? JumpSpotInfoController {
        print("eriubvwribvuorlaeD")
        if let senderAnnotationView = sender as? JumpSpotAnnotationView {
            let senderAnnotation = senderAnnotationView.annotation as? JumpSpotAnnotation
            jumpSpotInfoVC.titleLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.title
            jumpSpotInfoVC.imageView.image = senderAnnotation?.image
            jumpSpotInfoVC.descriptionLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.description
            jumpSpotInfoVC.heightLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.estimatedHeight
            jumpSpotInfoVC.warningsLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.warnings
            print("YOYOYOYO")
        }
    }
}
```

For the second segue, with identifier "JumpSpotInfo", I know the code is getting up to the if let statement because the print("eriubvwribvuorlaeD") shows up in the debugger, but I have no idea why the code inside the if let won't execute.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`?

Comment: Did you try to run this in the debugger? Is sender not nil and if so what type is it? `if let object = sender { print(type(of: object) }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson when I try to put that in, and I put the object in I get the error, Use of unresolved identifier 'senderAnnotationView'.  And for mag_zbc, I call it using the mapView calloutAccessoryControlTapped, using performsegue with the correct identifier and self

Comment: If you got that error you did something wrong. Only paste the code at the top of the function, don’t use `object` for anything else. My code is only meant for troubleshooting

Comment: @JoakimDanielson check the thread below, I got the error, now I'm just trying to figure out how I can work around it, if you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good example why force unwrapping can be very useful.

Force unwrap all optionals which are directly related to the segue. If the code crashes you made a **design** mistake which can be fixed immediately. The code must not crash if all classes and identifiers are set properly.

With optional binding nothing happens and you don't know why.

And you cannot assign the values to the labels directly. You need to declare properties in the destination view controller and assign the values in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    // Make sure we are acting on the correct segue
    if segue.identifier == "CreateJumpSpot" {
       let jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC = segue.destination as! JumpSpotCreatorController
        // Set the delegate in the JumpSpotCreatorController we're navigating to
        jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC.delegate = self
        
    } else if segue.identifier == "JumpSpotInfo" {
        let jumpSpotInfoVC = segue.destination as! JumpSpotInfoController          
        print("eriubvwribvuorlaeD")
        let senderAnnotationView = sender as! JumpSpotAnnotationView
        let senderAnnotation = senderAnnotationView.annotation as! JumpSpotAnnotation
        // create the following properties in JumpSpotInfoController
        jumpSpotInfoVC.title = senderAnnotation.title
        jumpSpotInfoVC.image = senderAnnotation.image
        jumpSpotInfoVC.description = senderAnnotation.description
        jumpSpotInfoVC.height = senderAnnotation.estimatedHeight
        jumpSpotInfoVC.warnings = senderAnnotation.warnings
        print("YOYOYOYO")
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried that I got the error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JumpSpotAnnotationView'... EDIT im realizing you took out the if let, gimmme a sec and lemme try that

Comment: Well then.  I got a SIGABRT: Could not cast value of type 'Jumper.MapViewController' (0x106539990) to 'Jumper.JumpSpotAnnotationView' (0x106539768).  My sender is the mapView controller, not the annotationView! How can I access the information of the SPECIFIC annotation/annotationView then, if it is not the sender? Because they each have different data contained within them

Comment: I don't know how the segue is triggered. If you perform the segue *manually* the `sender` can be customized.

Comment: the segue is triggered by tapping the .detailDisclosure type button on my rightCalloutAccessoryView when you tap on my annotation, is that considered manually? If so how can I customize it?

Comment: Connect the segue to the view controller, create an IBAction for the annotation and in the action method call `performSegue` passing the annotation as `sender`

Comment: could I not just change the sender in my func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)  function from self, to view?  I just did that and it worked, but now I get the error Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/Derek/Desktop/Xcode Projects/Jumper/Jumper/Controller/MapViewController.swift, line 91
(lldb)   So it's unwrapping nil for something? Not sure why

Comment: Don't change the method, but you can call `performSegue` in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped ` and pass the view as `sender` parameter. And don't forget to (re)connect the segue to the view controller.

Comment: that's what I meant (put view as the sender paramter) sorry, but when you say recconnect the segue to the view controller, why? I did, but I am still getting the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.  This is with regards to my annotation properties that I am trying to send over, but I know they exist.  Am I doing something wrong w the segue again? I even tested it, by putting a print(senderAnnotation.title) before the line with the error (jumpSpotInfoVC.titleLabel.text = senderAnnotation.title), and it printed the correct title...

Comment: What is the class of the enclosing view controller? And what is the origin of the segue?

Comment: CONT--- the correct title of the annotation.  So how could it be unwrapping a nil value? thanks for all your help

Comment: what do you mean by enclosing? the sending VC is MapViewController, the VC being presented is JumpSpotInfoController

Comment: A segue can be triggered in two ways: *Automatically* if it's connected to an UI element (for example a table view cell), or *manually* if it's connected to the view controller and calling `performSegue`. Apparently you are using the second way. So where do you call `performSegue`

Comment: I have performSegue in my mapView calloutAccessoryControlTapped function

Comment: Line 91 is jumpSpotInfoVC.titleLabel.text = senderAnnotation.title  .  I assume it's going to have the same error for each element below it as well.   But like I said Im not sure why it's unwrapping nil, because when I printed senderAnnotation.title right before it, it gives me the proper title, not nil

Comment: I got it. You cannot assign the strings to the labels, they are not connected yet. You have to use properties and assign the values to the labels in `viewDidLoad` in the destination view controller.

Comment: ahhh lemme try that real quick, if it works u r the best

Comment: OK, so it works (thanks so much) BUT I have one more weird issue.  My descriptionLabel, even though I'm giving it a value myself, is showing up as something weird like 'Jumper.JumpSpotAnnotation: 0x6008231038' everytime.  All the other values appear normally.  Why the heck is it giving me this? Im inputting values like "Awesome" or "Amazing", and I get this weird print lol.  Also one more thing, it's making me put everything in as jumpSpotInfoVC.titleInTransition = senderAnnotation?.title! as! String, then giving me a warning saying it only needs '!', not 'as! String', but if i change it.error

Comment: CONT ----- So that part just looks messy with all these annoying warnings it's giving me for no reason.  Jus that and the weird label problem is all I have left

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. Please ask a new one.